# bootstrap datetimepicker onChange event on start and end dates

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my project I got bootstrap datetimepicker for start and end dates and switch buttons which set dates for today, for last week and for all time. This looks like the following:

[image]

For datetimepickers I got onChange event and when the user changes either start or end date, ajax request is fired and new data is obtained from the server. he code for this is like this:

```
$("#datetimepickerFrom").on("dp.change", function (e) {                
    start_date = e.date;
    table.ajax.reload();
});

$("#datetimepickerTo").on("dp.change", function (e) {                
    end_date = e.date;
    table.ajax.reload();
});
```

So the problem is as follows: when the user clicks a button for last week, it sets today date for endtime datetimepicker and 7 days before date for start datetimepicker. As 2 datetimepickers are changed simultaneously, ajax request is fired **twice** and this is undesired behaviour. Any ideas how that could be avoided and ajax call made once in case 2 datetimepickers change?

Moreover I need to preserve ajax call for any datetimepicker change because user can change any of the dates manually and new data should be requested.

Thank you.

Comment: Tried using Promises and callbacks, and using callbacks to check if an ajax request already exists?

Comment: no, not sure how to do this. Could you show any example?

Comment: Instead of change event why dont you trigger same logic on Datepicker onClose event.

Comment: onClose event does not trigger ajax call when week or day button is clicked unfortunately

Comment: @Masha the answer below isn't right for you?

Comment: @Masha have you found another solution than mine?

Comment: unfortunately no, left it for later discussion, thank you for support

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code quickly a few minutes ago, and everything seemed working good. I've implemented a basic jquery ajax call. You can do your own as well.

```
<div class="container">
<div class='col-md-5'>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker6'>
            <input type='text' class="form-control" />
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class='col-md-5'>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker7'>
            <input type='text' class="form-control"/>
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Jquery part

```
let datePicker = {
 'dateStart': null,
 'dateEnd': null
}

$(function () {
  $('#datetimepicker6').datetimepicker();
  $('#datetimepicker7').datetimepicker({
    useCurrent: false 
  });
  $("#datetimepicker6").on("dp.change", function (e) {
    $('#datetimepicker7').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
      datePicker['dateStart'] = new Date(e.date._d);
    });
    $("#datetimepicker7").on("dp.change", function (e) {
      $('#datetimepicker6').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date);
       datePicker['dateEnd'] = new Date(e.date._d);
       if(datePicker['dateEnd'] && datePicker['dateStart']){
         $.post("your_url", datePicker, function(result){
           console.log(result)
         });
       }
   });
 });
```